# Why did Home Depot (.ca) try to sell me "Door Swings" with my fridge? What are they?

Tags: refrigerator

I was eyeing up delivery charges etc for a french door fridge I was buying, and homedepot.ca at that point informed me I should buy "door swings" (optional).

What are "doorswings"?  I found this page with zero information 
https://www.homedepot.ca/en/home/p.doorswings.1000116332.html

In this example I selected a $6000 fridge, and they want to nickel and dime me for another $25 for hardware to attach the doors?!

[image]

I ended up buying the fridge at lowes.ca, and neither they nor bestbuy had any warnings about 'doorswings'.

Please tell me I didn't just buy a $2000 fridge that doesn't include a way to attach the doors!

Comment: Oh, maybe all hardware is included, but if I want the delivery guy to attach the doors it will cost $25?

Comment: Lowes does not inform buyers of the option but they do sell it.

Comment: I suspect it's a generic price for reversing the swing of a single-door appliance. Obviously it wouldn't apply to your selection.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is not a hardware item it is a service.  It is placed in the list of options needed or not, you simple decline.   As you see there are two items listed as optional installation some are needed some are not.

It is used if the refrigerator door swings open the wrong way for your kitchen they will shift it to the other side.  In your case French doors are both directions so you simply decline.  Same as the haul away or relocation, if your install is new you have no unit to haul or remove so decline.

The salesman should have informed you on both of these as to why and given a decision to decline.  Bad salesman not bad service as they are trying to prevent you from receiving the unit and then finding out after it is on site that doors swing incorrectly or you do not know what to do with the old unit.

Comment: Thanks, I think it was because the sentence before talks about 'parts' that I misunderstood.  Btw, no salesman, it was all online.

Comment: @JimW Ah one of the few downfalls of online shopping.

Comment: it certainly seems like a poor design to offer you an option that doesn't apply to your unit, especially when there is no explanation of what it is.  i wonder what happens if you select the option, do they charge you for nothing?  put on the french doors backwards so they open at the at the ends instead of in the middle? (that would be a hoot!)

Comment: Bad online salesman, then ;)

Answer (score 0):

https://www.homedepot.ca/en/home/p.doorswing-service.1000116332.html

"Doorswing Service – the delivery agent will change the direction in which the door opens."

I was also doing an online purchase and was wondering what this service was.  Haul away was self explanatory for me, but not doorswing.

Comment: How is this different from the existing answer?